# Custom shape drawable in android programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

I want to make this custom shape in drawable in android studio. How to make this shape?

[image]

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: Explain what solutions you have already tried.

Comment: @Lino  - didn't try anything. because not getting any idea to get this shape.

Comment: @Dev4Life - didn't try anything. because not getting any idea to get this shape.

Comment: You can start drawing custom shapes by learning how to draw basic custom views.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:viewportWidth="908"
    android:viewportHeight="804"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="200dp">

    <path
        android:pathData="M0 0L541 0.5Q526.3 9.8 516 23.5Q497.1 45.6 487 76.5L482 96.5L481 110.5L480 111.5L480 142.5L486 174.5L498 202.5Q513.7 229.3 536.5 249Q565 273.5 599.5 292L638.5 312L709.5 345L750.5 369Q797.8 399.2 835 439.5Q869 476 890 525.5L898 548.5L904 574.5L904 579.5L906 586.5L906 594.5L907 595.5L907 607.5L908 608.5L908 633.5L907 634.5L907 647.5L906 648.5L906 656.5L905 657.5L903 675.5L895 708.5Q878.7 761 854 804L0 804L0 0Z"
        android:fillColor="#ECD3F3"
        android:strokeColor="#ECD3F3"
        android:strokeWidth="1" />
</vector>
```

Comment: How to draw this shape? I want to learn this vector drawable. Please tell me. This is exact same as like i want.

Comment: I used this site https://svg2vector.com/ However, this is not always accurate, so once xml is generated you can try playing with it, to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```html
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="908dp"
    android:height="804dp"
    android:viewportWidth="908"
    android:viewportHeight="804">
    <path
      android:pathData="M0,0L541.08,0Q515.69,19.78 500.21,47.45Q488.31,68.72 483.35,93.11C482.95,95.1 482.81,97.62 482.35,99.8C478.68,117.24 479.43,137.46 482.18,155.02C497.37,252.38 606.34,296.43 683.44,332.29C797.61,385.4 904.17,478.44 908,614.56L908,627.31C905.67,690.02 884.34,749.83 853.69,804L0,804L0,0Z"
      android:fillColor="#ecd3f3"/>
</vector>
```

How did I made it?

1. Downloaded your image
2. Uploaded [this](https://vectorizer.ai) website
3. The website gave me vector format of your shape.
4. I added android studio as a vector asset (You can see below)

Image 1: [Select This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfcna.png)
Image 2: [Browse svg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSlfV.png)

Comment: Sahin - Thank you very much for this solution. Now I can make any shape from this website. rhanks once again. you save my time.